# CSS3 Radial Gradient... Do percentage for Major and Minor axes (i.e., size) not work in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So this JSFiddle example works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  Pixels seem to work for Firefox, but Is there a way for me to use percentage for Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/ayjay/gVetP/2/

```
background-image:  -webkit-radial-gradient(150px 150px, 85% 30%, yellow, blue ); /*Chrome*/
background-image:  -moz-radial-gradient(150px 150px, 85% 30%, yellow, blue ); /*Mozilla*/
background-image:  -radial-gradient(150px 150px, 85% 30%, yellow, blue ); /*default*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**I recomend to use: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ in this cases...**

I recommend in general all online tools.. :P

As you can see, that is very useful:

```
background: #ffff00; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffff00 0%, #0000ff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#ffff00), color-stop(100%,#0000ff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffff00 0%,#0000ff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffff00 0%,#0000ff 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffff00 0%,#0000ff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffff00 0%,#0000ff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff00', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gVetP/6/